# UITextView text color and font not getting set

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSUserDefaults to store the following information:

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[settings setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"An Invitation.png",@"Apple Color Emoji ",[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[UIColor redColor]], nil] forKey:@"An Invitation"];
```

I am retrieving the same information in another class:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [settings dictionaryRepresentation];
for(id item in [dict allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"settings array is---- %@",[settings objectForKey:item]);
    if([[dict objectForKey:item] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        if([[settings objectForKey:@"CardImg"] isEqualToString:[[dict objectForKey:item] objectAtIndex:0]]) {
            NSLog(@"received font is ---- %@",[[dict objectForKey:item] objectAtIndex:1]);
            [self.txtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dict objectForKey:item] objectAtIndex:1]] size:20]];
            NSLog(@"received font is ---- %@",[[self.txtView font] fontName]);
            UIColor *txtcolor =(UIColor*) [ NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[dict objectForKey:item] objectAtIndex:2]];
            NSLog(@"received text color is ---- %@", [[dict objectForKey:item] objectAtIndex:2]);
            [self.txtView setTextColor:txtcolor];
        }
    }
}
```

The font and color in self.textView are not getting changed as per the value in dict. Upon printing `[self.txtView.font fontName]` I am receiving Null, but upon printing `[[dict objectForKey:item] objectAtIndex:1]`, I am getting "Apple Color Emoji". The font and color are getting set as per the default values in the XIB Attributes inspector. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

The font is nil because there is a space at the end of font name. And the colour needs to be unarchived. Remove the space from the font name and retrieve your saved settings this way:

```
NSArray *retrieved = [settings objectForKey:@"An Invitation"];

NSString *imageName = retrieved[0];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:retrieved[1] size:12];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:retrieved[2]];
```